# When does WordPress.org notify sites of new version?

Tags: plugins

I have a plugin in the wordpress.org repository and I have updated the plugin to a new version and that new version is reflected in the listing but my sites have the previous version. How long does it take before my new version is available to wp sites as an upgrade available?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 7):

> I have a plugin in the wordpress.org repository and I have updated the plugin to a new version and that new version is reflected in the listing

Congrats!

> but my sites have the previous version. How long does it take before my new version is available to wp sites as an upgrade available?

It should be immediate, but, .org doesn't notify your site. Instead, your site checks .org for updates. You can force it by going to the updates page and checking again:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

according to the wordpress developer FAQ: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/plugin-developer-faq/

> **How long does it take for the Plugin Directory to reflect my changes?**
>
> The WordPress.org Plugin Directory updates every few minutes. However,
>   it may take longer for your changes to appear depending on the size of
>   the update queue. Please give it at least 6 hours before contacting
>   us.